# WCF Service - Status

Tags: c#, wcf

I just need to return a response after saving the data parsed from the request but not sure how. What data type should be the method that i am using to save the data.

```
public string SaveData(RawData data)
{

    // save the data as txt file
    OutgoingWebResponseContext response = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;

    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    response.StatusDescription = "SUCCESS";
    return null; //??? what i should do here?
}
```

Comment: Well, you're method declaration indicates a `string` is returned, so I'd suggest just that - a `string`.

Comment: Why not return the `response` object?

Comment: So you've defined your own method and you've decided that it must return a string. Then you ask us to tell you what string to return?

Comment: guys please notice that i am a total noob when it comes to WCF. I just want a method that will return response with status 200 if everything went OK so i am not sure if it should be status or string or anything else. Please advice. Thank you

Comment: The response object is available from a static context to the caller, anyway. I would simply return void.

Comment: If you're using RESTful services, it would be a good idea to add the REST tag to your question to give it better context.

Comment: Thx for the suggestion though I am not sure if i use or if i don't use REST ... i just need it to saves the data and send confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use void as the return type of your method when you have no intention to return anything further.

public void SaveData(RawData data)
{
    ...
    // no need for any return here.
}

Comment: OK it makes sense but will i be able to read the status code only by declaring the status and set to success/OK  without returning value?

Comment: The caller of your method can access WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse to get to the same object instance that the method has modified.